# HTTPS for the Asus RT-N12 router's web interface

Tags: https

How do you access the Asus RT-N12 router's web interface via HTTPS? I've hunted through every page in the web interface, but haven't seen an option to enable HTTPS.

Comment: Not what you asked, but this router does support [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Asus_RT-N12) which does support HTTPS and other goodies.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Rich. I might just install DD-WRT on it.

Comment: It's a pain - I put DD-WRT on my Linksys.. it's better than stock Linksys firmware (never saw asus firmware, so can't comment). Seems to be worth it for me, and you can always go back (with some pain) if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Asus support agent told me that the router firmware doesn't support HTTPS.